# How to replace "match_expression\n" with preg_replace or other?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I wonder how to replace those matches `[/img]\n` (\n : new line) by `[/img]`, in a string.

I tried each of the following

```
$string = preg_replace("#[/img]\n#","[/img]",$string);
$string = preg_replace("/\[\/img\]\\n/","[/img]",$string);
$string = preg_replace("/\[\/img\]\n/si","[/img]",$string);
```

But nothing works...

```
$string = preg_replace("\n","Test",$string);
```

Works fine without the `[/img]` search.

I don't understand why I can't make it work.

**Example**

```
[img=y40h3inre6]Stock options[/img]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Should become the following :

```
[img=y40h3inre6]Stock options[/img]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try :

```
$string = preg_replace('~\[/img]\s++~', "[/img]\n", $string);
```

Or this

```
$string = preg_replace('~\[/img]\K\s++~', "\n", $string);
```

`\n` is for newline, but if you want match the string `'\n'` you must use `'\\\n'` instead in the pattern.

As notice Rikesh the new lines can be different on some systems (\n, \r\n, \n\r)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question `\n` = newline, not the string. Your solutions unfortunatly doesn't strip the `\n` from the `[/img]`.

Comment: @Valky : I have edited my post, since you show an example of that you want.

Comment: Great you found it (first one, with only `"[/img]"`) ! What a spectacular regex for a small problem... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Valky: You can do: `~\s++(?=\[img\b)~ => "\n"` or  `~\s++\[img\b~ => "\n[img"`

Comment: I forgot to tell you about the (.*?). So I made it work with `'~\s++\[img=(.*?)]~','[img=$1]'`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
echo $string = str_replace('[/img]\n',"[/img]",'abcd[/img]\nabcd[/img]\n');
```

## Output

```
abcd[/img]abcd[/img]
```

### Codepad